# Can't accomplish build with Jenkins, Symfony3 and PHPUnit 5.3

Tags: symfony, jenkins, phpunit

Trying to learn CI, I got stuck with the following problem:
Ant in command-line gives 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL' message.
When I push code to GitHub and run Jenkins on AWS, evth pass except PHPUnit part error:

```
> phpunit:
[phpunit] PHP Warning: require(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mavajob/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mavajob/app/autoload.php on line 9
[phpunit] PHP Stack trace:
[phpunit] PHP 1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
[phpunit] PHP 2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:29
[phpunit] PHP 3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:106
[phpunit] PHP 4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:117
[phpunit] PHP 5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:622
[phpunit] PHP 6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:793
[phpunit] PHP 7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:38
[phpunit] PHP 8. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:56
[phpunit] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mavajob/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mavajob/app/autoload.php on line 9
[phpunit] PHP Stack trace:
[phpunit] PHP 1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
[phpunit] PHP 2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:29
[phpunit] PHP 3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:106
[phpunit] PHP 4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:117
[phpunit] PHP 5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:622
[phpunit] PHP 6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:793
[phpunit] PHP 7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:38
[phpunit] PHP 8. include_once() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:56
[phpunit] Result: 255
```

I followed these instructions http://jenkins-php.org/automation.html
Maybe somebody could provide working examples for build.xml and phpunit.xml for Symfony3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you forgot to run `composer install` on the CI server before trying to execute PHPUnit.

Just add another target for composer (assuming you have composer already installed):

```
<target name="composer" description="Installing composer dependencies">
 <exec executable="composer" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="install" />
 </exec>
</target>
```

And make it a dependency of other targets that need it. For example, for `full-build`, you'd put it right after prepare:

```
 <target name="full-build"
         depends="prepare,composer,static-analysis,phpunit,phpdox,-check-failure"
         description="Performs static analysis, runs the tests, and generates project documentation"/>
```